# meaning of "nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object" when trying to reference an array within a member function

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++

I am confused as to why I am unable to use `arrValues`, `valuesBegin`, and `valuesEnd` despite my member function being publicly defined within a class which is a predecessor of `ArrayValues`.

I have the following code which is giving me trouble:

```
struct algorithms
{
    class arrayAlgs
    {
    public:
        int arrValues[100];
        int* valuesBegin = std::begin(arrValues);
        int* valuesEnd = std::end(arrValues);

        class ArrayValues
        {
        public:

            void createRandomArrayValues(){
            for(int& i: arrValues)
            {
                i = rand() % 100;
            }

        }
             void createAscendingArrayValues()
        {
                for(int* i = valuesBegin, d = 1;i <= valuesEnd; i++, d++)
            {
                *i = d;
            }
        }
        };
};
};
```

The following code is a class which stores algorithms but within it it has two member functions which create the environment for the algorithms to be used within, however this results doesn't build due to errors stating:

> "A non-static member reference must be relative to a specific object"

I am unsure of what this really means and how I can adapt my code without changing the variables so that the program runs smoothly.

Comment: they are members of `arrayAlgs`, the method you want to use them is of class `ArrayValues`

Comment: Why do you have `ArrayValues` as a nested class within `arrayAlgs`? Why is `arrayAlgs` itself a nested class within `algorithms`?

Comment: I have array and vector algorithms stored within the class so I have them in separate classes, It might be worth mentioning that I'm creating a program with my own implementations of each algorithm including vector and array algorithms so if it looks like overkill its just because I have gotten rid of lots of the other member functions and classes

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the error your code is more or less similar to this one:

```
struct algorithms { };

class arrayAlgs {
public:
    int arrValues[100];
    int* valuesBegin = std::begin(arrValues);
    int* valuesEnd = std::end(arrValues);
};

class ArrayValues {
public:
    void createRandomArrayValues(){
        for(int& i: arrValues) {
            i = rand() % 100;
        }
    }
    void createAscendingArrayValues() {
        for(int* i = valuesBegin, d = 1;i <= valuesEnd; i++, d++) {
            *i = d;
        }
    }
};
```

Just because you defined the classes nested within each other, does not imply that you can magically access members of an instance of the outer class. You still need an object of `arrayAlgs` to get access to its members `valuesBegin` and `valuesEnd`. You could for example add a `arrayAlgs` member to `ArrayValues` and then access its members.

However, your whole design seems to be based on a misunderstanding. It is not clear why you place everything in your code into a single class:

```
struct my_array {
    int arrValues[100];
    int* valuesBegin = std::begin(arrValues);
    int* valuesEnd = std::end(arrValues);

    void createRandomArrayValues(){
        for(int& i: arrValues) {
            i = rand() % 100;
        }  
    }
    void createAscendingArrayValues() {
        for(int* i = valuesBegin, d = 1;i <= valuesEnd; i++, d++) {
            *i = d;
        }
    }
};
```

Moreover, to iterate from begin till end you should use a range-based for loop:

```
 for (auto& e : arraValues) e = rand() % 100;
```

Comment: I have array and vector algorithms stored within the class so I have them in separate classes, It might be worth mentioning that I'm creating a program with my own implementations of each algorithm including vector and array algorithms so if it looks like overkill its just because I have gotten rid of lots of the other member functions and classes. It may looks silly right now but Its because the use of my program is to store many algorithms which can then be executed based on user input

Comment: @Ethan frankly, the fact that you removed a lot makes the design worse. A class definition should contain only the minimum needed to do one thing, not more. Don't try to stuff everything inside a class. Maybe you want to use namespaces instead

Comment: @Ethan anyhow, the nesting is not the actual issue. The issue is the same with or without nesting the classes: You need an instance to use its members

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I am saying that I removed a lot so that I could fit all of the things necessary for my question to be answered without anything extra, the program itself still contains everything

Comment: If you want to use `valuesBegin` which is a member of `arrayAlgs` inside `ArrayValues::createAscendingArrayValues` then you need an instance of `arrayAlgs`.

Comment: @Ethan do you understand why the code I posted with 3 seperate classes will cause a compiler error? The reason for your error is the same.